# Does the expression "a" < "A" evaluate to true or false? Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression

I believe this is false, because the strings do not have a value to be measured. However, I may be wrong so I'm hoping someone can offer a second opinion.

```js
console.log("a" < "A");
```

Comment: It is false, but for different reasons. See the ascii value for the characters on http://www.asciitable.com/ and compare. You are essentially comparing 97 < 65 which is obviously false.

Comment: @DavidSherret I did not, but I see now how that could have been beneficial. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: (It’s also trivial to check “A” < “a”..)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification @Xatenev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expression "a" < "A" evaluate to false, as it compare ASCII avlues of both char

```
"a" < "A"
"a".charCodeAt(0) < "A".charCodeAt(0)
97 < 65
```